# I have an error and due to lack of knowledge i dont no how fix this: "Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 8, in <module>

Tags: python

Write code that generates a list of N elements in
range from 1 to 100. Display the list on the screen. Insert value into list
k (keyboard value) in front of all elements,
ending with the number 8.

```
import random

n = int (input ('Enter the number of list items') )
list = [random.randint (1, 100) for i in range (n) ]
       print (list)

number = int (input ('Enter value.') )
l = [list.index (list % 10 == 8)]

while list % 10 == 8:
 list.insert (number)
```

Comment: The actual error message is the part after what you put in your question title.  Please put the full traceback into your question.

Comment: Just glancing at your code, though, it looks like you indented that `print (list)` line for no reason.  Also, you never want to name a variable `list` because that's a builtin name -- call it something like `items` or `nums` or literally almost anything but `list`.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `range()` instead.

```
l = list(range(1,100))
print(l)
k = []
for i in l:
    if i%10==8:
        k.append(i)
print(k)
```